# Call file in Rails with Ajax

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to learn to use Ajax in Rails.

In my Index.html.erb file:

```
function loadDoc() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function a() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
          document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("GET", "ex.html.erb", true);
      xhttp.send();
    }

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">click</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```

And in ex.html.erb file is :

```
<%= @a=1 %>
```

In browser,It just shows the content that: <%= @a=1 %>,it's not "1".So is that wrong ?

I'm new in Rails,so any tut for me,and I which way is good to do Ajax in Rails ? (I want to call file and do many actions:search,index,or do something with database)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your response to be processed by Rails, then you should use Rails structure. The way you are doing it, you're just requesting a file and it is working correctly serving you the file, but not as you need it.

I'd do it the following way:

1) Create a controller, say Whatever, using

```
$ rails g controller Whatever ex
```

This would create **app/views/whatever/ex.html.erb** and **app/controllers/whatever_controller.rb** with a method

```
def ex
end
```

and a route

```
get 'whatever/ex'
```

in your **config/routes.rb**.

2) Now you may change your code and the line who says

```
xhttp.open("GET", "ex.html.erb", true);
```

must now say

```
xhttp.open("GET", "whatever/ex", true);
```

I think this will do what you want.

Comment: By the way, here is a suggestion: http://rubyofftherails.blogspot.com/2015/12/a-small-trick-to-use-ajax-with-rails.html